# Upgrade Required SharePoint_Config

Tags: 2013, central-administration, content-database

When I go to "Manage Servers in Farm" from Central Admin, I see a red alert that says "Upgrade Required" against web front end. When I run the stsadm command

```
stsadm.exe -o localupgradestatus
```

, I get the following output:

```
<objects>
  <object>
    <name>SharePoint_Config</name>
    <type>Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase</type>
    <level>0</level>
    <status>Needs Upgrade</status>
  </object>
</objects>

[0] content database(s) encountered.
[0] content database(s) still need upgrade or cannot be upgraded.
[0] site collection(s) are contained in the content databases.
[0] site collection(s) still need upgrade.
[1] other objects encountered, [1] of them still need upgrade or cannot be upgraded.
```

I Tried psconfig command :

```
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait
```

and the result was:

SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard version 15.0.4569.1503. Copyright (C) M
icrosoft Corporation 2012. All rights reserved.

```
The upgradebootstrap command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
An error has occurred while validating the configuration settings.  An exception of      
type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown. Additional exception in
formation: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'proc_GetProductVersions',    
database 'SharePoint_Config', schema 'dbo'.
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do?

Comment: Hello, did you ever get a solution for this. I'm having the same issue just with an application server running search services.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but one of mine did this too. It worked on my test server, then I got this on our production server. I may have not ran the prompt as administrator, so when I tried again in as admin it worked.